# NullReferenceException in Visual Studio 2015 when viewing DTSX designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that we were using with BIDS 2008.

I've just opened in the Visual Studio 2015 and upgraded with the wizard, which passed without incident.

When I open the solution i can see all the file, view the XML of the dtsx file but when I open it in designer mode Visual Studio crashes with a `NullReferenceException`.  Details below:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.Msagl.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any advise on debugging\fixing this?

**Update**

Just tried creating a new solution and adding the file, and I have the same behaviour so I suspect the problem is in the dtsx file rather than the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread it's a bit old but the answer may help someone, try ungrouping all the grouped controls in the Control Flow, then migrate from 2008 to the version you want to, for some odd reason the grouping in older versions makes VS crash (the same happened to me in VS2013)